# Is it possible to do a 100% playthrough with a single save file?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I was thinking of doing my next playthrough to complete 100% of the game (I sort of rushed my first time), on the highest difficulty. Do I need to have multiple saves for branching scenarios, or is it actually possible to take a branch and then do some DnD shenanigans to get the results of all branches anyway?

Comment: What does "100%" mean in this game?

Comment: I think it may be possible to get 100% of achievements if you play a Dark Urge Tactician game, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft achievements and quests.

Comment: All achievements in one playthrough is much more possible, though it will require some save reloading near the end for all the different ending achievements. All quests is impossible because of mutually exclusive decisions as others have said.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple answer here is No. The game simply isn't designed for it.

There are certain scenarios that are mutually exclusive effectively locking you out of doing the other.

An example from Act 1 is

> Halsin vs Minthara - You will only be able to get one of them as a companion.

Comment: Another example is the choice which companion to hook up with. Some of them are OK with the player-character having *one* side-piece, but it's not possible to experience the romance plots with all the companions in a single playthrough.

Comment: Not to mention that the individual romance plots *also* have multiple routes and endings. Just like many of the other quests and side-stories in the game.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it on "one save", in the sense that you don't have to make another character. As Trappski had said, certain events/paths are mutually exclusive. You can play through the game on one path until you get all the achievements you can, and then load an older save.

This will let you do everything on one character, but I personally wouldn't say this is a "yes" answer to your question.

Comment: Keeping track of when and where a scenario-split begins can be pretty tedious though. And organizing that is probably a bigger endeavour than rolling a new char with a specific route through the game in mind.